# Setup in Ubuntu 14.04 for debugging CUDA code

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, debugging

I'm trying to set my machine with Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-59) for **debugging CUDA code**. I have an nVidia discrete card and an integrated GPU.

The plan is to have the **display connected to the integrated GPU** while the CUDA code gets executed and debugged. For that I need to have the nVidia driver installed.

I did that with the display connected to the discrete card and it disabled my nouveau driver. Now, I switched the display to the integrated card and I cannot login anymore using the GUI. I can login fine from the console.

Checking out the .xsession-errors gives me: *Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0"*

The main issue I have is that I need both the nVidia Driver and Nouveau Driver working in parallel for this.

Is this possible on Ubuntu 14.04? Windows does this with no problem. I'm thinking there must be a workaround for this on Linux.

Comment: AFAIK one instance of  `X server` won't use more than one driver at once. You could try to either nest multiple instances of `X` (I'm not sure how to do that) or you could just set your GUI stuff to use the `nVidia` driver. The settings pertaining to that should be in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (if you post its contents I/we can also probably help you set it up).